# Independent event condition probability

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed 10 times and the outcomes are listed. Let $H_i$ be the event that
the $i^{th}$ outcome is a head and $A_m$ be the event that the list contains exactly m heads. If
$H_i$ and $A_m$ are independent then find m.

Solution:

$P\left( {{H_i}} \right) = \frac{1}{2},P\left( {{A_m}} \right) = \frac{{{}^{10}{C_m}}}{{{2^{10}}}}$

$P\left( {{H_i} \cap {A_m}} \right) = P\left( {{H_i}} \right).P\left( {{A_m}} \right)$ condition for independent event.

How do we proceed from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $m = 5$, since you want $P(H_i)$ to be unaffected by the event that there are exactly $m$ heads.

Ordinarily, $P(H_i) = (1/2).$

If you are given that there are $m$ heads, then $P(H_i) = \displaystyle \frac{m}{10}.$

Comment: Yes the answer is correct but how do I solve it using independent probability concept

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi  The independent probability concept is that events $R$ and $S$ are independent if and only if $p(R) = p(R|S).$  $P(H_i) = (1/2) = P(H_i|A_5).$

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi You can also go at it from the other direction.  Ordinarily, $~\displaystyle P(A_5) = \frac{252}{1024}~$.  If you are given that $H_i$ is true, then $~\displaystyle p(A_5) = \frac{126}{512} = \frac{\binom{9}{4}}{2^9}.$